# How to find correct size inner tube

Tags: innertube

My tyre says 700x38 on the side of it.
what size inner tube would I need for the wheel? I've ordered a 700x35 inner tube but it seems a little too big for it?

Answer (score 10):

That will be fine.

38 is the measure of your tyre width.
Most inner tubes can be used in a range of tyre widths eg 38-43 (it should say on the box)
They all seem a bit big and flappy until the tyre is on and it's pumped up.

Be careful not to pinch any of your inner tube between the edge of the rim and the bead of the tyre.

Comment: Luke Allen -- if you liked the answer, it would be nice if you could click the button next to it to mark it as "accepted". That way Hitchmo gets some magical internet points. And you get +2 points. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer